# Python efficient way to copy one dictionary as value of key

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working on a monitoring tool in python.
It has a global dictionary with all hosts as keys and their details as values.

At the moment I do it like this:

```
host = hostname
hostDictionary["a"] = a
hostDictionary["b"] = b
hostDictionary["c"] = c
globalDictionary[host] = hostDictionary
```

My questions are:

1. Is this copying the whole hostDictionary into global's key or is it just referencing it?
2. Is there a better way to do this?
3. Is this faster?

   ```
   globalDictionary[host]["a"] = a
   globalDictionary[host]["b"] = b
   globalDictionary[host]["c"] = c
   ```

Comment: *"Is this copying the whole hostDictionary into global's key or is it just referencing it?"* It's just referencing it, e.g `a = {}; b = {'a': a}; b['a'] is a == True`. *"Is there a better way to do this?"* Maybe. Can you explain in more detail what you're trying to achieve? *"Is this faster?"* My guess is probably not, since you have a lot more overhead from the indexing.

Comment: How long does it currently take and how fast does it have to be? In the *vast* majority of cases, this optimization would be minuscule and not worth spending time giving a second thought.

Comment: @ali_m I am creating a dictionary of all hosts with it's details. Then a global dict which has the host as key and all it's value as details.
With this i can just query the global dict once for any host rather than finding the ip dict and querying it and any other fuction too can edit it if there's a change in any of it's properties.

Answer (score 1):

1\2 - It is a reference, you need to make a copy in this way.

```
from copy import copy  
globalDictionary[host] = copy(hostDictionary)
```

3 - I don't think so, I think that a copy to all the object can be quicker than access on each elements.

Answer (score 1):

1. Nopes, it ain't copying the whole dictionary, its just referencing it. To check this the best method is to do this -

   ```
   host = 'hostname'
   hostDictionary = {}
   globalDictionary = {}
   hostDictionary["a"] = a
   hostDictionary["b"] = b
   hostDictionary["c"] = c
   globalDictionary[host] = hostDictionary`
   ```

   Checking it -

   ```
   globalDictionary[host] is hostDictionary
   ```

   Output -

   ```
   True
   ```

   Which means both have the same id.
2. To copy you have to use, `copy()` or `deepcopy()`

   ```
   globalDictionary[host] = hostDictionary.copy()
   globalDictionary[host] is hostDictionary
   ```

   which gives youe `False` and proves its getting copied.
3. It depends on your purpose actually. But in any case direct assignment is obviously faster.

Answer (score 1):

I get this from Python CLI:

```
>>> a = {}
>>> b = {}
>>> c = {}
>>> a["foo"] = 1
>>> b = a
>>> c = a.copy()
>>> b["bar"] = 2
>>> a
{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}
>>> b
{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}
>>> c
{'foo': 1}
```

Which means:

1. You are just referencing `hostDictionary` in the key for `globalDictionary`. If you want a copy, call `hostDictionary.copy()` or `hostDictionary.deepcopy()` like hashcode55 said.
2. "Better" depends on your use case. But you could have just declared `hostDictionary = {'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c}`, for example.
3. It's slower on the Python interpreter side to do what you put there, since (assuming there's nothing built in to optimize things back to your original example) the engine will need to look up the object referenced by `globalDictionary[host]` for each operation before writing.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be faster if you initialize dict like this

```
lobalDictionary[host] = {
    "a": a,
    "b": b,
    "c": c
}
```

Also if you don't want to use copy or deepcopy, you can copy your dictionary like this:

```
globalDictionary[host] = dict(hostDictionary.items())
```

or

```
globalDictionary[host] = {k:v for k,v in hostDictionary.items()}
```